# Why is this recursive function not returning the value

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have been following the ebook Eloquent Javascript to learn javascript. In chapter 4 there is a challenge to access the nth value of a list using a recursive function. I have written a recursive function to do just that, but even though I can access the correct value, I can't return it for some frustrating reason.

I'm not sure if the definition of a list used by the book is universal so I here is an explanation. Basically each list element holds both a value, and the next list element. It's like some sort of inception. Here is an example.

```
list = {
    value: 1,
    rest: {
        value: 2,
        rest: {
            value 3,
            rest: null
        }
    }
}
```

So here is the code I am having a problem with.

```
function arrayToList(array){
  var list = {rest:null};
  for(var i = array.length-1; i>=0;i--){
    list = {
      value:array[i],
      rest:list
    }
  }
  return list;
}

/*
function nth(list, element){
  for(var i = 0;i < element;i++){
    list = list.rest;
  }
  return list.value;
}
*/

function nth(list, index){
  console.log(index);
  if(index < 1){
    console.log("Success", list.value);
    return list.value;
  }
  else {
    console.log("Fail");
    list = list.rest;
    index--;
    //console.log(index);
    nth(list,index);
  }
}

console.log(nth(arrayToList([10, 20, 30]), 1));
// → 20
```

The commented out nth function does what the book wants, but it's not recursive. Also there are a couple of extra `console.log()`s for debugging. As you can see, when I log "Success" and the value, it will log the correct value. However when I return the same value immediately afterward it returns undefined.

Comment: Forgetting to return the functional value, is something we've answered dozens of times.  I'm not finding the duplicate references for some reason.

Comment: How would I ever know that that was my problem unless I asked? I can't search for the answer to the problem if I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the value from you recursion...

```
function nth(list, index){
  console.log(index);
  if(index < 1){
    console.log("Success", list.value);
    return list.value;
  }
  else {
    console.log("Fail");
    list = list.rest;
    index--;
    return nth(list,index);
  }
}
```

Think like this -

Initial call **I** fails, so you recurse **R1** and fail, then recurse **R2** and succeed.

You correctly return the value from **R2** to **R1**, but you must then return from **R1** to **I** and back out the function.

Comment: That actually makes sense, let me try that.

Comment: I'll definitely have to re-visit this. It's totally frying my brain. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

To use recursion, function call must be returned

```
return nth(list,index);
```

Comment: Pardon my noob-ness but I don't understand. I tried both of the following, but neither worked correctly.

function nth(list, index){
   if(index < 1){
     return nth(list,index);
   }
   else {
     list = list.rest;
     index--;
     return nth(list,index);
   }
 }

 function nth(list, index){
   if(index === 0){
     return nth(list, index);
   } else {
     index--;
     list = list.rest;
   }
 }